# Find unknown factor in series so it converges to a given value

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm trying to find $F(z)$ such that:

$$\lim_{N \to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N F\left(\exp\bigg(\frac{2 \pi i n}{N}\bigg)\right) \cdot \log\left|\exp\bigg(\frac{2 \pi i n}{N}\bigg) - \exp(i \theta)\right| = \\\log|a \exp(i \phi) - \exp(i \theta)| $$

where $a \in (0, 1)$ is fixed.

I thought I could express this as an integral:

$$\begin{matrix}\displaystyle
\int_0^{2\pi} F\big(\exp(it)\big) \log|\exp(it) - \exp(i \theta)| dt &= \log|a \exp(i \phi) - \exp(i \theta)| \\
\displaystyle\oint F(z) \log|z - \exp(i \theta)| \frac{dz}{iz} &= \log|a \exp(i \phi) - \exp(i \theta)| \\
\end{matrix}$$

in which case

$$F(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{z}{(z - a \exp(i \phi))}$$

However when I plug in this $F(z)$ and do some example partial sums I get values which are not close to the expected values and are not even off by a constant factor, which makes me think I've screwed something up.

Comment: There is no $\phi$ on the left of the first display and it appear on the right.  Is $\phi$ a parameter to $F$ that has been suppressed on the left?  (Your last display has $F$ depending on $\phi$ without making that explicit in "$F(z)$".)

Comment: Yeah you can think of it as $F(z, \phi)$ if that helps.  I didn't mark it as a parameter because it doesn't vary over the sum.

Comment: @JayLemmon I think you screwed up in the question. The sum should be multiplied by $\frac{1}{N}$ so that it is the integral you claimed it is.

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't know for sure it's the integral I claimed it was; that may be where I made the mistake.  The sum itself is ultimately "correct", in that it's what I'm trying to find, and since my integral expression didn't actually give me the desired result it's entirely possible it's incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution concerns for the case when the sum is equal to zero.

$\lim\limits_{N \to\infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N F\left(e^{\frac{2 \pi i n}{N}}\right) \cdot \ln\left|e^{\frac{2 \pi i n}{N}} - e^{i \theta}\right| = \ln|a e^{i \phi} - e^{i \theta}|$

Let's transform the $\ln$ part of LHS:

$\ln\left|e^{\frac{2 \pi i n}{N}} - e^{i \theta}\right|=\overbrace{\ln|e^{\frac{\pi i n}{N}-\frac{i\theta}{2}}|}^0+\ln|\overbrace{e^{\frac{\pi i n}{N}-\frac{i\theta}{2}}-e^{-\frac{\pi i n}{N}+\frac{i\theta}{2}}}^{2i\sin(\frac{\pi n}{N}-\frac{\theta}{2})} |$

Let  $F=\frac{1}{N}F^*$ we have the following Riemann sum:

$\lim\limits_{N \to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N F^*\left(e^{\frac{2 \pi i n}{N}}\right)\ln|{2\sin(\frac{\pi n}{N}-\frac{\theta}{2})}|=\int\limits_0^1F^*\left(e^{2 \pi i x}\right)\ln|{2\sin(\pi x-\frac{\theta}{2})}|dx$

Using that $\int f'(x) f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}f^2(x)+c$

$f(x)=\ln|{2\sin(\pi x-\frac{\theta}{2})}|$

$f'(x)=F^*(e^{2 \pi i x})=\pi |\cot(\pi x-\frac{\theta}{2})|$

We get:

$\int\limits_0^1\pi |\cot(\pi x-\frac{\theta}{2})|\ln|{2\sin(\pi x-\frac{\theta}{2})}|=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2|{2\sin(\pi x-\frac{\theta}{2})}|\Big|_0^1=0$

So  $\ln|a e^{i \phi} - e^{i \theta}|$ must be equal to $0$.

$a(a-2\cos(\theta-\phi))=0$

As $a \in (0, 1)\rightarrow$  $a=2\cos(\theta-\phi)$

Finally $\theta=\cos^{-1}(\frac{a}{2})+\phi$

Comment: Thanks, looks like the sum is divergent unless $F(z) = 0$, which I wasn't expecting.

Comment: Thank you for the question and the points.